# Why does Delphi warn when assigning ShortString to string?

Tags: delphi

I'm converting some legacy code to Delphi 2010.

There are a fair number of old ShortStrings, like string[25]

Why does the assignment below:

```
type 
  S: String;
  ShortS: String[25];

...
S := ShortS;
```

cause the compiler to generate this warning:

```
W1057 Implicit string cast from 'ShortString' to 'string'.
```

There's no data loss that is occurring here.  In what circumstances would this warning be helpful information to me?

Thanks!

Tomw

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ShortString type has not changed.  It continues to be, in effect, an array of AnsiChar.

By assigning it to a string type, you are taking what is a group of AnsiChars (one byte) and putting it into a group of WideChars (two bytes).  The compiler can do that just fine, and is smart enough not to lose data, but the warning is there to let you know that such a conversion has taken place.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Since it's safe, I just figured the warning was superfluous.

Anyway, congrats on D2010. I'm enjoying the transition so far.  The white papers you all provided (especially Cary's) are very helpful.

Comment: Please consider removing "is smart enough not to lose data". There's just no way this could *ever* happen, all compiler "smartness" aside.

Comment: This CAN make you lose data, simply because not all values from 0-255 in a shortstring are well defined in all code pages.

Comment: @Lars: I do of course assume the Ansi string being encoded in the current code page. Otherwise the data has already been changed, see my comment to your answer.

Comment: @mghie: That's a dangerous and often incorrect assumption. Most of my shortstrings are in old encryption, compression modules and modules that analyze binary data, and shortstring-to-unicodestring assignment was one of the things that we had to remove when upgrading these modules, in order to prevent data loss.

Comment: @Nick: This is an example, where data is lost: Code, that reads utf-8 directly from a file using blockread into a shortstring, saves the text in a tstringlist, and then pulls it out from tstringlist into a shortstring or an ansistring. This works perfectly in Delphi 2007, but in Delphi 2009, that code would lose/corrupt data on PCs with certain code pages (like CP 932). The corruption/data loss will happen during the shortstring to string assignment.

Comment: In Delphi 2010, the code insight (CTRL+SPACE) says the Shortstring is defined as `ShortString : String[255]`, so Unicode.Yet its "string types" documentation mentions a size of 2..256 bytes, so AnsiChar !?

Comment: Maybe the warning is there in order to let the user know (when he upgrades his old programs to a modern version of Delphi) that an old feature (shortstring) is still in use?

Answer (score 20):

It's because your code is *implicitly* converting a single-byte character string to a UnicodeString.  It's warning you in case you might have overlooked it, since that can cause problems if you do it by mistake.

To make it go away, use an *explicit* conversion:

```
S := string(ShortS);
```

Answer (score 7):

The warning is very important because you may lose data. The conversion is done using the current Windows 8-bit character set, and some character sets do not define all values between 0 and 255, or are multi-byte character sets, and thus cannot convert all byte values.

The data loss can occur on a standard computer in a country with specific standard character sets, or on a computer in USA that has been set up for a different locale, because the user communicates a lot with people in other languages.

For instance, if the local code page is 932, the byte values 129 and 130 will both convert to the same value in the Unicode string.

In addition to this, the conversion involves a Windows API call, which is an expensive operation. If you do a lot of these, it can slow down your application.

Comment: You can get more information here: http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/delphi-unicode-migration.pdf&pli=1

Comment: I'm sorry, but the byte values 129 and 130 in that code page are the DBCS lead byte and have only meaning together with the trailing byte. Check out http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP932.TXT. IMHO if the source string contains invalid DBCS sequences it's wrong to speak of losing data. That has been lost before.

Comment: For example by loading character data in a different code page, without the proper conversion.

Comment: Shortstrings often contain data from various sources, and even though the conversion assumes that the content of shortstring uses the local code page, it often doesn't. It may contain binary data, data from an external file that uses a different encoding etc.

If you get data from an external file that uses a different code page, save it to shortstring, and convert to unicodestring, there may be no way that you can recover your original data. That's data loss.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but loading files into strings in the way you describe has been a problem in Ansi Delphi versions already. Loading such a file has already changed the data, which can be seen when it's displayed. That's data loss too. Ignorance of code pages leads to data loss.

Comment: @mghie: Not correct. The question is only about assignments of shortstrings to string. When string=ansistring, you can always assign from shortstring to string without data loss - but when string=unicodestring, that is no longer true.

Comment: @mghie: A good example where data is lost, is some code, that reads utf-8 directly from a file using blockread into a shortstring, saves the data in a tstringlist, and then pulls it out from tstringlist into a shortstring. This works perfectly in Delphi 2007, but in Delphi 2009, that code would lose/corrupt data on some PCs.

Comment: @Lars: Your example is convincing, I agree. I never considered this, having abandoned short strings many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe ( as long as you're using the ShortString for its intended purpose: to hold a string of characters and not a collection of bytes, some of which may be 0 ), but may have performance implications if you do it a lot. As far as I know, Delphi has to allocate memory for the new unicode string, extract the characters from the ShortString into a null-terminated string (that's why it's important that it's a properly-formed string) and then call something like the Windows API MultiByteToWideChar() function. Not rocket science, but not a trivial operation either.

Answer (score 1):

ShortStrings don't have a code page associated with them, AnsiStrings do (since D2009).

The conversion from ShortString to UnicodeString can only be done on the assumption that ShortStrings are encoded in the default ANSI encoding which is not a safe assumption.

Answer (score -4):

I don't really know Delphi, but if I remember correctly, the Shortstrings are essentially a sequence of characters on the stack, whereas a regular string (AnsiString) is actually a reference to a location on the heap. This may have different implications.

Here's a good article on the different string types: 
http://www.codexterity.com/delphistrings.htm

I think there might also be a difference in terms of encoding but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Uri: Since Delphi 2009, string is WideString not AnsiString.  The warning has nothing about which memory structure/location is the variable allocated in.

Comment: @jachguate: Thanks. ADmittedly, I haven't touched Delphi since the very early 2000s.