# Upgrade from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2009

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-7

I have a Delphi 7 project in which there are some record types containing strings loaded and stored to files.
After recompiling with Delphi 2009, when the program loads the records from file, strings get messed up because the compiler expects Unicode while the file has Ansi strings.
The type is similar to this:

`type

    Tpoint = record

    name: string[255];

    x, y: integer;

end;`


After substituting "string" with "ansistring" the project doesn't even compile saying 
"E2029 ';' expected but '[' found".
Suggestions?

Comment: I think I will make the old application save as Unicode, looks simpler

Comment: M.G. don't be too sure. Looks like you're giving up real easy.

Answer (score 4):

**shortstring** (which string[255] is) is still interpreted the same way as before: [an array of AnsiChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121265/why-does-delphi-warn-when-assigning-shortstring-to-string/2121379#2121379) with the first byte as its length. **ansistring** can not be defined as an array, therefore the error message.

How do you read the file to fill the records? And how do you fill them? Maybe the error occurs there.

Comment: As Ralph says, it should still work. You should not have to change any string[##] declarations.