# Why does Str() give "W1057 Implicit string cast from 'ShortString' to 'string'"?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe2

Consider:

```
function x_StrZero(N: Double; W: Integer; D: Integer = 0): String;
var S : String;
begin
  Str(N:W:D,S);   
  S := Trim(S);
```

This gives W1057 Implicit string cast from 'ShortString' to 'string'

The [online doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Str) says:

```
procedure Str(const X [: Width [:Decimals]]; var S: String);
```

but also

> Notes: However, on using this procedure, the compiler may issue a warning: W1057 Implicit string cast from '%s' to '%s' (Delphi).

Why would this be?

I would like to prevent this ugly workaround:

```
function x_StrZero(N: Double; W: Integer; D: Integer = 0): String;
var
  S : String;
  SS : ShortString;
begin
  Str(N:W:D,SS);
  S := Trim(String(SS));
```

I have read [Why does Delphi warn when assigning ShortString to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121265/why-does-delphi-warn-when-assigning-shortstring-to-string) but that does not answer this.

Comment: you can use *format* if this workaround is ugly for you

Comment: just a wild guess, did you tried S:Ansistring and {$O-} ?
Str is ancient function from TurboPascal, probably asm implementation over TP strings. While IntToStr lacks that functionality, i'd anyway avoid those ancient procedures.

Comment: TJclNumericFormat and function IntToStrZeroPad(Value, Count: Integer): string; may be feasible replacements too

Comment: The correct approach is to stop using `Str`

Comment: I agree with you, it *is* ancient code

Comment: DOS-era Turbo-pascal compatibility syntax.  You can't add your own functions with func(a:b:c,d) syntax. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Str(N:W:D,S);
```

gets compiled as

```
S := System._Str2Ext(N, W, D);
```

where `System._Str2Ext` is a function with a return type of `ShortString`. It gets converted to `string` in the assignment to `S`. The warning, while not easily readable, is correct, there is an implicit conversion at that point. So either rework the code to not have an implicit conversion there by avoiding `Str`, or turn off the warning, or ignore the warning.

Comment: Thanks, I did not find that in System

Answer (score 0):

You can turn that specific warning off. It's just a reminder, and most of the time your program works fine. I guess the compiler still sees `String` as `ShortString` in the functions which are built into it like `Str()` and `Writeln()`.

Comment: You meant Shortstring rather than AnsiStirng probably ? And WriteLn finely works with string==UnicodeString

Comment: Yes my mistake. I meant routines which are replaced by the compiler directly